# How do I get this mathematical rounding?

Tags: vb.net, math, operators, finance

This is what I see in an official tool, and I need to calculate the same end value:

[image]

For clarification:

I am given the numbers 95, 3, 5, 19 and 17.15.

I am trying to replicate a math formula in VB.NET in order to achieve the same sum as a government financial tool that I must stay conform with.

The official tool's result and mine differ by 0.1 €, and I don't see what I need to do to achieve the same result.

The official tool states:

```
A product costs 95.00 € net.
Somebody buys 3 pieces of it.
He gets a discount of 5 % (=4.75 €)
19% VAT is added: 17.15 €
The net price is then 90.25 €
The price is now 270.75 €
The resulting end price is now 322.19 €.
```

The values that I am given are these:

```
net price for 1 piece: 95 €
amount: 3
discount per piece: 5%
VAT amount: 19%
VAT: 17.15
```

First, I calculate the discount like this:

```
Dim amount As Integer = 3
Dim discount As Double = 5
Dim VAT As Double = 17.15
All result As Decimal 

Discount = (amount * discount) / 100 = 4.75
Discounted net price per piece = 95 - 4.75 = 90.25
Discounted net price per piece plus vat = 95 + 17.15 = 107.4

Total price result = discounted net price per piece * amount = 107.4 * 3 = 322.2 €
```

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong by choosing a wrong operator?

Is it even possible to get the same amount as they do with the information that I am given?

Thank you.

Comment: 95 * (1 - 0.05) * 3 * 1.19 = 322.1925 = 322.19 to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I just realised that you actually did use the correct discounted net price in the calculation below but you just wrote that you didn't, i.e. the result is correct even if the operands aren't.

ORIGINAL:

You do this:

> Discounted net price per piece = 95 - 4.75 = 90.25

but then here:

> Discounted net price per piece plus vat = 95 + 17.15 = 107.4

you don't use the result of that previous calculation.

Also, even if you did use the discounted price, how does it make sense to add a percentage to a price? Surely you need to calculate that percentage of that price, then add that result to that price. I would think that that line should be this:

> Discounted net price per piece plus vat = 90.25 + (90.25 * 17.15 / 100) = 105.7(27875)

Comment: I do know that theoretically VAT should be 19%. But I do not have this value to calculate with. I have the VAT amount of 17.15. That is what I am given to calculate with.

Comment: @tmighty, the actual number is irrelevant. VAT is a percentage of the price. You don't just add the VAT number to the price. That would mean that you would be adding the same number no matter what the price was. Didn't you learn how to calculate percentages in school? This is a basic maths problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: I am given the numbers 95, 3, 5, and 17.15.

Officially, I do not have the number 19.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of what I see in the official tool. I need to be able to calculate their calculated end result of 322,19 € from the values that I am given.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Decimal Data Type (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/decimal-data-type#remarks):

> The Decimal data type provides the greatest number of significant
> digits for a number...It is particularly suitable for calculations,
> such as financial, that require a large number of digits but cannot
> tolerate rounding errors.

Try the following:

Create a `Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)` with the following `TextBox` names:

- TextBoxPrice
- TextBoxQuantity
- TextBoxDiscountPercentage
- TextBoxVATPercentage
- TextBoxNetSalesPrice
- TextBoxVATAmount
- TextBoxGrossSalesPrice

and a `Button` (name: btnCalculate).

[image]

Try the following:

```
'for testing
Private cultureInfo As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")

'ToDo: use this one to use the current culture info of the computer
'Private cultureInfo As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

'get currency symbol
Private currencySymbol As String = cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim InitialPrice As Decimal = 95
    Dim Quantity As Decimal = 3
    Dim DiscountPercentage As Decimal = 5
    Dim VATPercentage As Decimal = 19

    'set value
    TextBoxInitialPrice.Text = InitialPrice.ToString("N2", cultureInfo)
    TextBoxQuantity.Text = Quantity.ToString("N0", cultureInfo)
    TextBoxDiscountPercentage.Text = DiscountPercentage.ToString("N0", cultureInfo)
    TextBoxVATPercentage.Text = VATPercentage.ToString("N0", cultureInfo)
End Sub

Private Sub Calculate()
    Dim DiscountAmount As Decimal = 0
    Dim DiscountPercentage As Decimal = 0
    Dim NetPrice As Decimal = 0
    Dim InitialPrice As Decimal = 0
    Dim Quantity As Decimal = 0
    Dim VATAmount As Decimal = 0
    Dim VATPercentage As Decimal = 0
    Dim GrossSalesPrice As Decimal = 0

    'ToDo: Ensure that the user entered valid input. If not, notify the user of invalid input

    'convert String to Decimal
    Decimal.TryParse(TextBoxInitialPrice.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, cultureInfo, InitialPrice)
    Decimal.TryParse(TextBoxDiscountPercentage.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, cultureInfo, DiscountPercentage)
    Decimal.TryParse(TextBoxVATPercentage.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, cultureInfo, VATPercentage)
    Decimal.TryParse(TextBoxQuantity.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, cultureInfo, Quantity)

    Debug.WriteLine($"A product costs {InitialPrice.ToString("N2", cultureInfo)} {currencySymbol} net.")
    Debug.WriteLine($"Somebody buys {Quantity.ToString("N0", cultureInfo)} pieces of it.")

    'calculate discount amount
    DiscountAmount = Decimal.Multiply(InitialPrice, Decimal.Divide(DiscountPercentage, 100))
    Debug.WriteLine($"He gets a discount of {DiscountPercentage.ToString("N0", cultureInfo)}% (={DiscountAmount.ToString("N2", cultureInfo)} {currencySymbol})")

    'calculate net price
    NetPrice = Decimal.Subtract(InitialPrice, DiscountAmount)
    Debug.WriteLine($"The net price is then {NetPrice.ToString("N2", cultureInfo)} {currencySymbol}")

    'calculate gross price
    Dim NetSalesPrice As Decimal = Decimal.Multiply(NetPrice, Quantity)
    Debug.WriteLine($"The price is now {NetSalesPrice.ToString("N2", cultureInfo)} {currencySymbol}")

    'set value
    TextBoxNetSalesPrice.Text = NetSalesPrice.ToString("N2", cultureInfo)

    Debug.WriteLine($"{VATPercentage.ToString("N0", cultureInfo)}% VAT is added to this amount.")

    'calculate VAT amount
    VATAmount = Decimal.Multiply(NetSalesPrice, Decimal.Divide(VATPercentage, 100))

    'set value
    TextBoxVATAmount.Text = VATAmount.ToString("N2", cultureInfo)

    'calculate grand total (gross sales price)
    'GrossSalesPrice = Decimal.Multiply(NetSalesPrice, Decimal.Add(1, Decimal.Divide(VATPercentage, 100)))
    GrossSalesPrice = Decimal.Add(NetSalesPrice, VATAmount)

    Debug.WriteLine($"The resulting end price is now {GrossSalesPrice.ToString("N2", cultureInfo)} {currencySymbol}")

    'set value
    TextBoxGrossSalesPrice.Text = GrossSalesPrice.ToString("N2", cultureInfo)
End Sub
```

**Usage**:

```
Calculate()
```

---

[image]

---

**Update**:

From the code above one can extract the following formulas which were created using the information listed beneath *The official tool states*:

**Formulas**

```
DiscountAmount = InitialPrice * (DiscountPercentage / 100.0)
NetPrice = InitialPrice - DiscountAmount
NetPrice = InitialPrice - (DiscountAmount)
NetPrice = InitialPrice - (InitialPrice * (DiscountPercentage / 100.0))
NetSalesPrice = NetPrice * Quantity
VATAmount = NetSalesPrice * (VATPercentage / 100.0)
GrossSalesPrice = NetSalesPrice + VATAmount
```

**Given the following**:

- **NetPrice**: 95
- **Quantity (amount)**: 3
- **DiscountPercentage**: 5%
- **VATPercentage**: 19%
- **VATAmount**: 17.15

**Formula #1**: DiscountAmount = InitialPrice * (DiscountPercentage / 100.0)

**Formula #2**: NetPrice = InitialPrice - (DiscountAmount)

If one substitutes the `DiscountAmount` formula, in `Formula #2`, one has:

```
NetPrice = InitialPrice - (InitialPrice * (DiscountPercentage / 100.0))
```

**Let's insert the information into the formulas**:

```
95 = InitialPrice - (InitialPrice * (5 / 100.0))
95 = InitialPrice - (InitialPrice * 0.05)
```

Let's change `InitialPrice` to something that may be more familiar: `x`

```
95 = x - (x * 0.05)
95 = 1x - 0.05x
95 = 1.00x - 0.05x
95 = 0.95x
```

**ToDo**: Solve for `x` (InitialPrice).

---

**Formula**: NetSalesPrice = NetPrice * Quantity

Insert the information into the formula:

```
NetSalesPrice = 95 * 3
NetSalesPrice = 285
```

---

The information regarding `VATAmount` and `VATPercentage`, in the OP,  seems to keep changing. Nevertheless, one uses simple algebra to solve for the unknown variable.

**Formula**: VATAmount = NetSalesPrice * (VATPercentage / 100.0)

Insert the information into the formula:

```
VATAmount = 285 * (19 / 100.0)
```

**or given `VATAmount = 17.15` instead of a `VATPercentage`**:

```
17.15 = 285 * (VATPercentage / 100.0)
```

Once again, let's change `VATPercentage` to something that may be more familiar: `x`

```
17.15 = 285 * (x / 100.0)
17.15 = 285x / 100.0
17.15 * 100 = 285x
1715 = 285x
```

**ToDo**: Solve for `x` (VATPercentage).

---

**Resources**:

- [Decimal.Multiply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.multiply?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Decimal.Divide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.divide?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Decimal.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.add?view=netframework-4.8)
- [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8)
- [NumberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: Thank you, but these are not the values that I have. I do know that VAT should be 19. But I don't have that value to calculate with. I need to use the VAT amount (17.15 €).

Comment: I have added a screenshot of what I see in the official tool. I need to be able to calculate their calculated end result of 322,19 € from the values that I am given.

Comment: I used the information listed under _The official tool states_. Feel free to modify the code as needed to calculate the numbers based on the information that you've been given.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://www.mathopolis.com/questions/quizzes.php